# Self-referencing function, DOM element, & Javascript garbage collection

Tags: javascript, dom, garbage-collection

I'm wondering about the limits of Javascript garbage collection and whether it can be tripped up by self-reference.

Imagine a div attached to the document. Now lets add a custom attribute to it: a function to operate on said element:

```
(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  el.custom_func = function() {
      el.style.color = 'green';
  };
})();
```

Finally, we later remove the element from the DOM.

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
el = null;
```

Assuming that there are no other references to this element, will it get garbage collected normally?

Is there *any* way in which a custom attribute on a DOM element could mess up garbage collection?

Comment: Back in the day it was a problem in Internet Explorer. I doubt it's worth worrying about now. I could be wrong however.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that there are no other references to this element, will it get garbage collected normally?

Yes.

> Is there any way in which a custom attribute on a DOM element could mess up garbage collection?

The gist of garbage collection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Limitation_objects_need_to_be_made_explicitly_unreachable

```
var green = 'green';
(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  el.custom_func = function() {
      el.style.color = green;
  };
})();
```

In the this example the DOM element will get garbage collected. The `green` variable will not prevent garbage collection on the element.

```
var colors = {
  green: 'green';
};

(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  el.availableColors = myColors;
  el.custom_func = function() {
      el.style.color = el.availableColors.myColors.green;
  };
})();
```

Even in this 2nd case, the element will be garbage collected because it only holds a pointer to the `colors` object.

More about garbage collection here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management